# express cannot find nested routes if they're not in controller's file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to establish a maintainable route pattern for my express api. I have a top level router which handles the controllers. **If I place the `AwsController.get('/s3', ...)` logic in the same file as where the `AwsController` is defined, it works.** However, I'd like to break my nested routes into separate nested files for organizational reasons. When I try importing the `AwsController` into `services/aws/s3` it no longer works. Any thoughts as to how I can get this pattern to work?

**route controller**

```js
interface IRoutes {
  path: string;
  controller: Router;
}

const _routes: IRoutes[] = [
  { path: '/', controller: IndexController },
  { path: '/services', controller: ServicesController },
  { path: '/services/aws', controller: AwsController },
];

export const routes = (app: Application) => {
  _routes.forEach((route) => {
    const { path, controller } = route;
    app.use(path, controller);
  });
};
```

**file for `services/aws` paths**

```js
export const AwsController: Router = Router();

AwsController.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('aws controller works');
});

// if I define the '/s3' path shown below in this file it works.
```

**file for `services/aws/s3` paths** -- this path cannot be reached by express

```js
import { AwsController } from './AwsController';

AwsController.get('/s3', (req, res) => {
  res.send('s3 works');
  // doesnt work -- says: Cannot GET /services/aws/s3
});
```

Comment: services/aws works because your exporting the router which then is used in the forEach, your not doing that with services/aws/s3, if you want it to work your need to import it into services/aws

Comment: I'm trying to avoid creating a bunch of controllers for each service and instead just have them all exist under their parent platform (aws in this case). Right now, the above code works if I define the `/s3` path **in the same file as where the `AwsController` is defined.** However, what I want to do is move the `/s3` route out of the the script my `AwsController` is defined and put in in a separate directory without having to create a new controller and adding it to my router. I thought importing the `AwsController` would work (shown above) but no luck.

Comment: perhaps this is an importing issue and not an express issue? I don't see why I can't import `AwsController` into a different file for the sake of organization.

Comment: make services/aws/s3 export a router, or just the function, then inside services/aws, import services/aws/s3, and define it onto the router.

Comment: Hey @LawrenceCherone , wanted to reach out. Thanks for your input regarding fixing this problem. I've gone ahead and made those changes. I suppose at the time of the question I was looking at it wrong. Thanks!